# Unity launcher crashes and leaves ghost shadow

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

Sometimes my Unity launcher crashes and shows and undesirable behaviour: although it still hides, it leaves a ghost shadow behind it. I don't know how to solve it and the only way to recover the functional desktop is restarting the session.

Find attached a screenshot that shows what I'm trying to describe:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! There's no need to sign your posts since your name appears in the lower right corner.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to "re-init" the unity by command `unity --replace` or if persists reset everything with `unity --reset`? Note that the latter will replace your launcher icons with original ones that came with installation (you will loose current config)
If that does not resolve the issue add unity daily ppa and update your unity version. I use ppa version and it is more stable than bare bone one!

Comment: Hi Stefano, that solves the problem in the short term without the need to log off. Great!! No I'll wait to see if it keeps happening...

Comment: Unfortunately it's still happening from time to time :'(, any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered upgrade unity to ppa version?
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:unity/daily